# BooleanField Model not showing the default False value but '-' instead

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-admin, django-modeladmin

I have a model `class` where the variable `completed_application` should default to `False` when creating a new user (to show that the user hasn't completed an application yet). However, by default when a new user is created it doesn't show as `False` in Django admin but '-' instead.

**models.py:**

```
class Company(models.Model):
    class Meta:  
        verbose_name_plural = 'Company'
    user = models.OneToOneField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    company_name = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)


class Completed(models.Model):
    class Meta:  
        verbose_name_plural = 'Completed Application'
    user = models.OneToOneField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    completed_application = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

**admin.py:**

```
class Company(admin.StackedInline):
    model = Completed
    can_delete: False
    verbose_name_plural = 'Completed Application'


class UserAdmin(UserAdmin):
    list_display = ('username', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'email', 'company', 'completed')
    search_fields = ('username', 'email',)
    inlines = [Company]
    list_filter = ('is_active',)
    fieldsets = (
        (None, {'fields': ('username', 'password')}),
        (('Personal info'), {'fields': ('first_name', 'last_name', 'email')}),
        (('Permissions'), {
        'fields': ('is_active', 'is_staff', 'groups',),
    }),
        (('Important dates'), {'fields': ('last_login', 'date_joined')}),
)
```

[image]

[image]

The red arrow in the first image above points to the Users admin panel for a newly created user. The second image shows the individual user in Django admin with the custom model added to that user.

Other point to note: Checking the box and saving the user it shows `True` (as to be expected), but then unchecking the box and saving the user it eventually shows `False` and not '-'.

Could someone explain what this '-' means and how to ensure the model always shows False on creation?

Comment: Did the problem solve?

Comment: @SunderamDubey unfortunately not yet. I have even changed the BooleanField to CharField and get the same issue. Would mind looking at the code I just edited it? I'm now wondering whether another class that I didn't include in the original post using the same custom user model in models.py might be interfering?

Comment: You can share your GitHub repo if possible, I'll check that.

Answer (score 2):

From the docs, the [`can_delete`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.InlineModelAdmin.can_delete) should be `can_delete=False` not <s>`can_delete:False`</s>

Comment: Thanks this helped bug fix but it doesn't solve the problem. The main issue in my question still persists.

Comment: @Olney1 Try `default=0` in BooleanField, maybe it can help.

Comment: Just tried that and applied migrations but still the same issue.

Comment: @Olney1 Anyway will see it later and reply to you bye :)

Answer (score 0):

I believe it is the cant_delete that is passed false, try to remove it

Comment: Well, it is `can_delete` and written as `can_delete=False`, it defaults to True.